# Is there something like printf in Action Script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I searched it for while but didn't find anything like printf in Action Script.

That makes it a little difficult to generate formated strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Printf-as](http://www.stimuli.com.br/trane/2009/feb/21/printf-as3/) is a third-party library that will handle this. [Here](https://github.com/arthur-debert/printf-as3/) is the GitHub repo. From the README:

```
printf("You can also display numbers like PI: %f, and format them to a fixed precision, 
        such as PI with 3 decimal places %.3f", Math.PI, Math.PI);
// outputs: " You can also display numbers like PI: 3.141592653589793, 
// and format them to a fixed precision, such as PI with 3 decimal places 3.142"
```

It also plays well with dates:

```
var date : Date = new Date();
printf("Today is %d/%m/%Y", date, date, date);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's too limited to be useful, things like `%-12s` do not work.

Answer (score 7):

think you might be looking for StringUtil.substitute()

take a look here: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/StringUtil.html#substitute

Comment: broken link, try this one: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/StringUtil.html#substitute()

Comment: that said, I don't like it: it has none of the useful features of printf, and it offers no feature more than a simple string concatenation with `+` could do.

Comment: While StringUtil does not have the number formatting capability of `sprintf`, it is useful in that it allows separating the template generation from the formatting action that is also a useful feature of `sprintf`. And the fact that it is builtin and does not require external code is a large plus in my book.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Formatter classes that you could use or create custom formatters.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=createformatters_2.html

Comment: the mx.formatters.Formatter is a generic "lets manipulate strings" base class that has none of the capabilities of `sprintf()`, not even the field substitution a-la Java's MessageFormat, that `StringUtil` has (from @Acatl Pacheco's response). Its also not really ActionScript generic - I doubt if it makes sense outside MXML.

Answer (score -1):

The only function I know that prints to a standard output is trace() (debug purposes only) , which can take virtually any type of variable.

I might not have understood your question, though.

Comment: Actually, I mean something like "sprinf".  I don't need to send text to console.  I need to generate formatted strings.

Comment: What for ?
On a TextField ?

Typing is very limited in AS3  (Number, int, String, basically), I think you may want to give us more details about what you want to do.